# oracle how can check if 'time' not date between two date Fields with time

Tags: sql, oracle

Q1 - i have this task where i want to check if there is no overlap in "time" between two dates fields (start_date , end_date) and their time 
, the time i want to check is in the same date with the start and end date

any ideas or tips

Q2 -

```
select 
    extract( hour from
        to_timestamp(
            to_char('04/04/2018 04:05:05','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
        )
    ) as v_to 
from dual;
```

Returns :

> **ora-01722** *invalid number*

My NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT is 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'

Comment: "TO_TIMESTAMP converts char of CHAR, VARCHAR2, NCHAR, or NVARCHAR2 datatype to a value of TIMESTAMP datatype."   "TO_CHAR (datetime) converts a datetime or interval value of DATE, TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, or TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE datatype to a value of VARCHAR2 datatype in the format specified by the date format fmt. If you omit fmt, then date is converted to a VARCHAR2 value as follows:"  So you need to use a CAST i geuss to convert datetime datatype into a timestamp datatype? `... to_timestamp(CAST(to_char('04/04/2018 04:05:05','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) AS timestamp)...`

Comment: Q1 : please define what you call « a time overlap between two dates »

Comment: i had a time with the same date as the stored start and end date coming ****

 i have to check if the new time dose not comes between the the stored time in the start and end date ****

E.g.
start = ' 04/04/2018 10:30:00 ' ****
end = ' 04/04/2018 12:30:00 ' ****

 if the new = '04/04/2018 11:00:00 ' return error msg 
if not take it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1 : you can compare dates using regular comparison operators, so to check if a given date belongs to a date interval, you need :

```
...my_date >= start_date AND my_date <= end_date
```

Or :

```
...my_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
```

Q2 - This does not work because of the TO_CHAR call, that expects a date as first argument (not a string) and returns a string, which is no good for consumption by TO_TIMESTAMP.

You should skip TO_CHAR and start with TO_TIMESTAMP :

```
select
    extract( hour from
        to_timestamp('04/04/2018 04:05:05', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
        )
    ) as v_to 
from dual;
```

Comment: thank you very much , it works fine 
i missed that to_char takes date not string

but what about my first question

Comment: for my Q1 : i had a time with the same date as the stored start and end date coming **** i have to check if the new time dose not comes between the the stored time in the start and end date **** E.g. start = ' 04/04/2018 10:30:00 ' **** end = ' 04/04/2018 12:30:00 ' **** if the new = '04/04/2018 11:00:00 ' return error msg if not take it